# Why did I get a Null/Loopback after I send a packet with pcpp?

Tags: pcapplusplus

I have a nginx instance running on `localhost:80` and I want to send it a raw TCP SYN packet.

So I generate a dummy packet and send it to `lo` interface via pcapplusplus. However, when the Wireshark is monitoring the `lo`, it says this packet is `Null/Loopback` and did not do more things, it seems. But if I write this packet to a `pcap` file, Wireshark can recognize it well. Two packet data is 100% same.

I'm a bit confused and what is the best practice to accomplish my needs?

Comment: What operating system is this on?

Comment: Ubuntu server 22

Comment: Where did Wireshark say that the packet is Null/Loopback?  On Linux, loopback device packets have *Ethernet* headers, not *BSD loopback* headers (which is what "Null/Loopback" refers to).